# How to check for the key from Tree Map in JSF

Tags: jsf

I hope this question is clear and you could help me.I'm a new to JSF .

I created one Tree Map in my Bean(ProdBean.java) to show the menu list in JSF and select Menu in JSF `ShowList.xhtml` as follows.

ProdBean.java

```
public Map<String, String> getOnlineMap (){
private static final Map<String, String> prodMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
    if(prodMap == null || prodMap.isEmpty()){
         prodMap.put("PROD_MAP_1", "ISSUE_S1");
         prodMap.put("PROD_MAP_2", "ISSUE_S2");
         prodMap.put("PROD_MAP_3", "ISSUE_S3");
    }

    public Map<String, String>  getCategoryList() {
    selectItemList = getOnlineMap ();
    return selectItemList; 
    }
```

ShowList.xhtml

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="enquiryType"  style="width:300px">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Select"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{ProdBean.categoryList}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I would like to show the prompt message only the key if "PROD_MAP_1"  by checking  ProdBean.categoryList in JSF when selecting the Menu List but I don't know how to check the condition by getting key and value from Tree Map in JSF.If anyone could help me, I truly appreciated for your support.

Thanks.

Comment: why map for select items. use List

Comment: for whatever be the reason he might be using a Map, there would be an option for keys to be used, try using keyset method similar to the below post that i have put in...

Comment: because I would only show the key in Menu List and I'd like to get the value of this Map to use in another function after selecting Menu List. 
Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: just tell me how to add html code to this - i was not able to do - please suggest

Comment: You might need to add xml namespaces for jsf and richfaces in your html tag.

Comment: I am not asking for doing programming rather if i post my html code in stackoverflow its not showing up in the below pane to post it. And if i post it its not coming up. Please suggest I have the answer

Comment: please select your code and then "Ctrl+k"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and it worked - i posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just check this out - this is how you access it.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.integerProperty}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.mapProperty.entrySet()}" var="entry" 
     itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```